# how to format json display and get response

Tags: c#, json, wcf

```
public FooMessageType Foo(string name, string password)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sample"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee where username='" + name + "' and password='" + password + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rd.Read())
    {
        return new FooMessageType { Name = name, Password = password, msg = "welcome" };
    }
    else
    {
        return new FooMessageType { Name = name, Password = password, msg = "error" };
    }
}
```

---

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "aw")]
FooMessageType Foo(string name, string password);
```

---

```
[DataContract]
public class FooMessageType
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "msg")]
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

---

this is the request data

```
{ "name": "123","password": "123"}
```

this is the response data

```
{"msg":"error","name":"123","password":"123"}
```

What I want request is

```
{LoginRequest:{"username": "123","password":"123"}}
```

and response

```
{LoginResponse:{"responseCode":"1","responseMessage":""
userDetails: {"firstname":"","lastname": ""}}}
```

Anyone can help me create the class to display this data and get the response ? I'm new in creating wcf.

Comment: That's invalid JSON.

Comment: So you're asking how to add a property to a class? What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Comment: i dont have no idea to create a property class

Comment: Make a regular class, then make a property of that type.

Comment: please show me example im not good in words sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
class OuterClass { 
    public InnerClass MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class InnerClass { ... }
```